# How to not compile certain Android menu items on 'release' builds

Tags: android, debugging, release, menuitem

I have a certain menu item I call 'debug' that does some things that are handy for 'debug' releases. I want this menu item not to exist on 'release' APKs.

Is there a way to tell the compiler to ignore those entries in the XML menu file?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using menu XML resources, you can isolate those debug-only choices into their own resource XML file. Then, in addition to inflating your main one, you also inflate the debug-only one, if `BuildConfig.DEBUG` is `true`:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
  // inflate that second resource XML file
}
```

If you are setting up your menu using Java code, you can do the same basic thing, wrapping the debug-only `add()` calls in a check of `BuildConfig.DEBUG`.

The upcoming Gradle-based build system will help to make this a bit easier, in principle, but that is several months away at this point AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jenkins to create your builds you can replace your debug menu xml file with the production one using shell commands.  This is also very effective with webservice detail xml files.